# Canvas section between two areas with clip

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, web

So I have pretty annoying problem which I find hard to understand and fix.
I want to have section between two areas in HTML5 canvas - one is a rectangle the other one is complex figure made with lines (pictures below):

[image]

The red figure is the complex area and the below light blue is rectangle which has part of it on the red figure.

I want to visualize only the area which has both the read and the blue area (the pink-ish color at the center).

The best I can do is this but is pretty inaccurate because the figure is distorted somehow.

[image]

This is the result I want:

[image]

I really don't know what seems to be the problem. Here is the code for the [FIRST](https://jsfiddle.net/binevv/c2ojkdx6/9/) and [SECOND](https://jsfiddle.net/binevv/c2ojkdx6/8/) pictures:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var pts = [
  {
    "x": 144.54545454545456,
    "y": 357.3227658791164
  },
  {
    "x": 313.6363636363636,
    "y": 357.83576331700544
  },
  {
    "x": 482.72727272727275,
    "y": 390.79970884062334
  },
  {
    "x": 651.8181818181818,
    "y": 342.08032949810206
  },
  {
    "x": 820.909090909091,
    "y": 359.5816507117245
  },
  {
    "x": 990,
    "y": 394.7374924508338
  },
  {
    "x": 1159.090909090909,
    "y": 375.44796552459445
  },
  {
    "x": 1328.1818181818182,
    "y": 348.80309018743964
  },
  {
    "x": 1497.2727272727273,
    "y": 387.65889083719674
  },
  {
    "x": 1666.3636363636363,
    "y": 361.47353311915924
  },
  {
    "x": 1835.4545454545455,
    "y": 389.24337978312957
  },
  {
    "x": 1835.4545454545455,
    "y": -10000
  },
  {
    "x": 144.54545454545456,
    "y": -10000
  },
  {
    "x": 144.54545454545456,
    "y": 357.3227658791164
  }
],
bufferSpace = 2,
clipX = 144.5,
clipY = 245,
clipWidth = 1692,
clipHeight = 580;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(pts[0].x, pts[0].y + bufferSpace);
for (var i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
  var pt = pts[i];
  ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y + bufferSpace);
}
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
////ctx.fillStyle = fillcolor;
ctx.fillRect(clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);

//ctx.save();
//ctx.clip();

//ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
//ctx.fillStyle = fillcolor;
//ctx.fillRect(clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);
//loadPatternImage(clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);

//ctx.restore();
```

clip case:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var pts = [
  {
    "x": 144.54545454545456,
    "y": 357.3227658791164
  },
  {
    "x": 313.6363636363636,
    "y": 357.83576331700544
  },
  {
    "x": 482.72727272727275,
    "y": 390.79970884062334
  },
  {
    "x": 651.8181818181818,
    "y": 342.08032949810206
  },
  {
    "x": 820.909090909091,
    "y": 359.5816507117245
  },
  {
    "x": 990,
    "y": 394.7374924508338
  },
  {
    "x": 1159.090909090909,
    "y": 375.44796552459445
  },
  {
    "x": 1328.1818181818182,
    "y": 348.80309018743964
  },
  {
    "x": 1497.2727272727273,
    "y": 387.65889083719674
  },
  {
    "x": 1666.3636363636363,
    "y": 361.47353311915924
  },
  {
    "x": 1835.4545454545455,
    "y": 389.24337978312957
  },
  {
    "x": 1835.4545454545455,
    "y": -10000
  },
  {
    "x": 144.54545454545456,
    "y": -10000
  },
  {
    "x": 144.54545454545456,
    "y": 357.3227658791164
  }
],
bufferSpace = 2,
clipX = 144.5,
clipY = 245,
clipWidth = 1692,
clipHeight = 580;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(pts[0].x, pts[0].y + bufferSpace);
for (var i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
  var pt = pts[i];
  ctx.lineTo(pt.x, pt.y + bufferSpace);
}

//ctx.closePath();
//ctx.fill();

//ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
////ctx.fillStyle = fillcolor;
//ctx.fillRect(clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);

ctx.save();
ctx.clip();

ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
//ctx.fillStyle = fillcolor;
ctx.fillRect(clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);
//loadPatternImage(clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);

ctx.restore();
```

Edit:

This is my real case scenario. This is the graphic I have:

[image]

And this is the graphic I want:

[image]

You can see the red and blue part which has lines inside is kind of incorrect!

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the main section after defining the complex shape with:

```
//... complex shape defined...
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(205, 41, 89)";  // set target color here
ctx.fill();

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";

ctx.fillRect(clipX, clipY, clipWidth, clipHeight);
```

This will build a mask only keeping the shape that is intersected ("destination-in"). Also set target color right away - do this using a known value or mix it on the fly.

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/c2ojkdx6/10/)**

**Update** to address the new information in the question - you can do this operation on an off-screen canvas. When done, simple draw that off-screen canvas back on top of your other graphics as an image (canvas can be used directly as image source, i.e.: `ctx.drawImage(offCanvas, x, y);`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately this doesn't work in my real case scenario because I have much bigger graphic and this wipes out all other content of the canvas. For example I want to have another section above this one and also lines and graphics. That's why I was using "save", "clip" and "restore". Can I mix your answer and mine in some way?

Comment: I also Edited my original post to see the real case scenario and how it should be!
Thanks for your help

Comment: @IvanBinev I updated the answer. Simply go by a temporary or off-screen canvas, then draw the result on top of the main canvas.